# React Conditional Rendering in a Map Statement

Tags: reactjs

I'm a SharePoint developer working on my first SPFx/React program. Currently, I'm trying to conditionally map a list of countries onto buttons. This code works fine:

```js
{spListItems && spListItems.map((list, index ) =>
  <p >
  <button  type = "button" className={styles.btn} onClick={()=>this.clickHandler(list.UniqueId)}>{index} + {list.Title}</button>
  </p>
    )}
```

While this code doesn't work:

```
{spListItems && spListItems.map((list, index ) =>
   {if (index > 20){
      <p >
      <button  type = "button" className={styles.btn} onClick={()=>this.clickHandler(list.UniqueId)}>{index} + {list.Title}</button>
      </p>
     }
   }
 ) 
}
```

A few notes:

I've run the code through the debugger and all seems fine, the build succeeds, the index has a value and the debugger shows the correct code is being executed. Yet the first example renders the buttons as expected while the second doesn't render anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have to return

Comment: Yeah, you have to return something (returning null in the `else` case). Although you should be doing this differently anyhow, just do `spListItems.slice(20).map(...)` (that skips the first 20 items of the array. It might be off by one, you'll have to test.)

Answer (score 0):

**.map()** does not change the original array. It will always return a new array . in your example you're not returning from it
**just change  :**

```
{spListItems && spListItems.map((list, index ) =>
   {if (index > 20){
      <p >
      <button  type = "button" className={styles.btn} onClick={()=>this.clickHandler(list.UniqueId)}>{index} + {list.Title}</button>
      </p>
     }
   }
 ) 
}
```

**to :**

```
{spListItems && spListItems.map((list, index ) =>
   {if (index > 20){
      return (<p >
      <button  type = "button"  onClick={()=>this.clickHandler(list.UniqueId)}>{index} + {list.Title}</button>
      </p>)
     }
   }
 ) 
}
```